# jQuery dataTables - minimum column width and table horizontal scroll

Tags: datatables

I'm having two issues with Datatables. 
First, I need to choose a minimum column width and if the content is bigger, the column must be resized to the content width.

And, I'm trying to use the following code to have horizontal scrollbars, but it's causing problems with the size and positioning of the header cols and the content cols.

```js
$(".dataGrid").dataTable({
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "sScrollX": "100%",
    "sScrollXInner": "110%",
    "bScrollCollapse": true
});
```

Comment: What kind of problems are you having?

Comment: I just removed the datatables from my Project until I find the fix, but the problem is that the columns in the header row are smaller than the columns in the data rows, then the values from column B (just an example) seems to be at column A.

Comment: can you post a jsbin or some more source?

Comment: This problem is very old. I don't know why the question has been edited. Please ignore it